# What data should i test in functional testing?

Tags: testing, functional-testing

I've just finished reading this article about functional testing :

[Functionnal Testing PDF](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/edu/testingdebugging10/slides/01-Functional%20Testing.pdf)

And there is a point i want to talk about. At the page 13, he ask what values for a, b, c we should test to garantee that the feature of the Root class is working.

I have the exactly same question but for a more complex exemple.
I have database and a save method. The save method feature is to save data in the database. To test if the feature is working i follow the nexts instructions :

1. I initialize a test data.
2. I use the save method to put it in the database
3. I reload the data from the data base
4. I compare the initial data and the loaded one.

If the datas are the same, i can conclude that the save method feature is working.
Is this test sufficient to ensure that my method is working ?
because it seems to be a little too simple.

Comment: Are you asking whether that's an adequate happy-path test or whether that's the only test of that method that you need?

Comment: I'm asking for both. What i'm looking for is a way to test this method that will ensure that it is working. But i don't really have an idea of how to do it.Should i test with different entry, like when the method should give me an error ?

Comment: This would suffice if you talk about the functional aspect . This seems to be simple as you might not have many combination of data. Consider a use case where there is a million of data with 10000 different combination.